# How can I create a 301 rewrite rule in NGINX for all locales?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a website with three locales.

I want to create a permanent redirect where `https://sitename.com/locale-name/article-name` gets redirected to `https://sitename.com/locale-name/articles/article-name`.

the `locale-name` can equal en, fr, or es.

I also need to account for the default locale, which will just got to `https://sitename.com/articles/article-name`

and... I also have a few other pages, like `https://sitename.com/info`

How can I create a 301 redirect for all three locales, while accounting for all other cases?

I've tried this,

`rewrite ^/(en|fr|es)/((?!info|articles).*)$ $1/articles/$2 permanent;`

which I think should do it for the most part, but won't account for default locale.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't verified this, but you can try something in the lines of

```
rewrite ^/(en|fr|es)/(.*)$ /$1/articles/$2 permanent;
```

You can look for more examples [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: thanks, but I need to account for a few other cases too. I've updated my question also if you want to give it another shot.

Comment: Please be more specific. From your updated question - I think it should work well enough with the rewrite I provided.